# android Declaring Unicode strings as html

Tags: android, xml, string, unicode

I am trying to add new strings to an android project's localized XML file.

There is a static string array defined in a localized xml file(eg. zh-TW/mystrings.xml

), where the strings are like.

```
<string-array name="translate_language_names">
    <item>&#38463;&#25289;&#20271;&#25991;</item>
```

Problem: when I am adding a new string, I was thought I could just put an actual Unicode string as: 南非荷蘭文

But I see it is encoded in an HTML style format.

Can anyone tell how to encode these Unicode strings to HMTL style encoding?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are bunch of sites that seem to do this. Search for convert  Unicode to html entities. That worked.